# Why do some things always show up in the HUD when using other applications, but not others

Tags: 12.04, menu, hud

I have noticed that some menu items always show up in the HUD regardless of which application is focused (e.g. Messages > Chat), but others only show up when the application is focused (e.g. Chat > New Conversation).  What controls this behavior and how easy is it to add new global actions that target a specific application (e.g. I want to be able to create a new conversation from anywhere).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For HUD, the rule seems to be, you can do something with only those things that you can see.

You can ALWAYS see app-indicators, so all menu items related to these are always available.

But for other applications, the menu items are available only when you are 'in' that application.

Comment: So, to accomplish what I desire, I would need to write an indicator that exposes the global functions I want to perform?

Comment: Unless it is already written by someone else :)

And yes, if this answers your question, please accept the answer. That will help all of us - you, me and others who have a similar question.